# CoreData NSManagedObject subclass - Expected identifier

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode5, nsmanagedobject

When I generate my NSManagedObject from my data model, my header from the NSManagedObject is almost full red. It says "Expected ')'" and "Unexpected '@' in program". It's not just one header file, but all of them from the generated NSManagedObject.

### Steps

1. I create a new entity in my data model (Name and Class have the same name)
2. I generate my NSManagedObject (New File -> Core Data -> NSManagedObject subclass)

When I follow these steps, the code of my header file turns red..

I use XCode 5.1.1 (5B1008). I has worked before, but suddenly I got these errors. I removed all CocoaPods just in case that caused these errors, but it didn't fix it.

### Code header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Menu : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mod_date_updated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * mod_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mod_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mod_route;

@end
```

### Data model

[image]

### Errors

[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you didn't include (before line 9 in your code) some file which is missing an @end from an interface/protocol/anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I solved my problem.
I had a bracket somewhere in my main file on a place it shouldn't be.

So. My experience with this error is looking after some misplaced letters :)